# Dojo DEPRECATED dojo.moduleUrl

Tags: dojo

Hellow I have one project and while running it I got some warnings:

> DEPRECATED: dojo.moduleUrl() use require.toUrl -- will be removed in
>   version: 2.0

but where is no "*moduleUrl*" uses in my project, does anybody know how to fix it ? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Dojo you are using, but I assume it is 1.9. According to a quick scan `dojo.moduleUrl()` is used in the `dojox` section about 40 times. `dojo.moduleUrl` itself is reporting that it is deprecated.

I would expect that when Dojo 2.0 comes out all the dojox widjets will be upgraded accordingly and your worries will be at an end.

**Update**: Just noticed a similar answer has been posted while I've been thinking of mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some code in the `dojox` package still uses this function.  Are you using anything from the `dojox` package?

If you want to find out what code is calling it, use the uncompressed dojo files and put a breakpoint in `dojo/_base/kernal` on ~line 282 (depending on version).  When the breakpoint is hit, look at the call stack.

This message is only a warning and not an error, so your code isn't broken.